# Program Calculator Using PHP for computation and a HTML input form

Tags: php, html, variables

I'm a PHP newbie and I tried to setup a Calculator in PHP (HTML).

Problem:

I want to php script to call itself to process the input values.
My goal is to avoid php session to cache the values. To be specific I have two different fields - one output field, which is readonly and a input field, where numeric values can be entered. In addition to that there are 5 different buttons to calculate addition, subtraction, multiplication, division and assign values in the input field.
I was only able to solve the problem with Session Variables like in following example. I use a own-defined session, which I try to replace with normal PHP variables and I want to update them everytime one of the operation buttons are pressed. In addition the input values should be saved as well as the output to be able to use the same value again without the need of reentering it to the form.

Basically, I want to replace all the session variables like "$_SESSION['output']" by php variables like "$output". All I've already tried was not working, because the values were overwritten each time I recall the script (or by calling itself).

```
<?php session_start(); 

// Session Timeout:
if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 60)) {
    // last request was more than 1 minute ago
    session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time 
    session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
}
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>PHP Calculator</title>
<style type="text/css">
#add {
    color:black;
    background-color:#F55;
}
#subtract {
    color:black;
    background-color:#55f;
}
#multiply {
    color:black;
    background-color:#5f5;
}
#divide {
    color:black;
    background-color:#ff5;
}
#exp {
    color:black;
    background-color:#fa2;
}
#equal {
    color: black;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
.res {
    color: black;
    font-style: italic;
    background-color:#eee;
    border: none;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<?php 
    if (is_null($_SESSION['output'])){
        $_SESSION['output'] = "0.0"; 
    }

// Operations to execute via form.
$_SESSION['input'] = $_POST['input'];

if(isset($_REQUEST['add'])){
    $_SESSION['output'] += $_POST['input']; 
} else if (isset($_REQUEST['subtract'])) {
    $_SESSION['output'] -= $_POST['input']; 
} else if (isset($_REQUEST['multiply'])) {
    $_SESSION['output'] *= $_POST['input']; 
} else if (isset($_REQUEST['divide'])) {
    if($_POST['input'] == 0) {
        $_SESSION['output'] = $_POST['input'];  
    } else {
        $_SESSION['output'] /= $_POST['input']; 
    }
} else if (isset($_REQUEST['exp'])) {
    $_SESSION['output'] = pow($_SESSION['output'], $_POST['input']);    
} else if (isset($_REQUEST['equal'])) {
    $_SESSION['output'] = $_POST['input'];  
} else {
    $_SESSION['input'] = 0.0;
}
?>

<form name="calculator" action="index.php" method="post">
<input class="res" type="text" readonly="readonly" size="23px" value="Result:" />
<input class="res" type="text" readonly="readonly" size="20px" value="Input:" />
<input class="res" type="text" readonly="readonly" size="10px" value="Operations:" /><br>
<input name="output" type="text" readonly="readonly"  value="<?php print ($_SESSION['output'])?    >"/>
<input name="input" type="text" onfocus="this.value=''" value="<?php print ($_SESSION['input'])?    >" />
<input id="add" name="add" type="submit" value="+" />
<input id="subtract" name="subtract" type="submit" value="-" />
<input id="multiply" name="multiply" type="submit" value="*" />
<input id="divide" name="divide" type="submit" value="/" />
<input id="exp" name="exp" type="submit" value="^" />
<input id="equal" name="equal" type="submit" value="=" />
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

What is the most simple way to solve that?

Comment: What is "each time". Page reload with F5 key?

Comment: Why not use the $_POST variable to get the values from the form, process them then output the result?

Comment: another question.. 
is there a way, so that the 0.0 in the output field is really "0.0" (the comma) and not "0"? I can force it with %f, but when I do that, then I can't get higher precisions if I use the division operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution will be to use `$_POST` variables :

Replace

```
if (is_null($_SESSION['output'])){
    $_SESSION['output'] = "0.0"; 
}
```

by

```
$output = (isset($_POST['output'])) ? floatval($_POST['output']) : 0.0;
```

And then replace `$_SESSION['output']` in your code by `$output` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here the same script without session, while keeping the "session" time out working (As long as you don't close/refresh the page)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>PHP Calculator</title>
<style type="text/css">
#add {
    color:black;
    background-color:#F55;
}
#subtract {
    color:black;
    background-color:#55f;
}
#multiply {
    color:black;
    background-color:#5f5;
}
#divide {
    color:black;
    background-color:#ff5;
}
#exp {
    color:black;
    background-color:#fa2;
}
#equal {
    color: black;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
.res {
    color: black;
    font-style: italic;
    background-color:#eee;
    border: none;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<?php
$lastActivity = (int)(isset($_REQUEST['last_activity']))?$_REQUEST['last_activity']:time();
$output = (float)(isset($_REQUEST['output']))?$_REQUEST['output']:0;
$input = (float)(isset($_REQUEST['input']))?$_REQUEST['input']:0;


// "Session" timeout
if(time() - $lastActivity > 60){
    $output = 0;
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['add'])){
    $output += $input; 
} else if (isset($_REQUEST['subtract'])) {
    $output -= $input; 
} else if (isset($_REQUEST['multiply'])) {
    $output *= $input; 
} else if (isset($_REQUEST['divide'])) {
    if($input == 0) {
        $output = $input;  
    } else {
        $output /= $input; 
    }
} else if (isset($_REQUEST['exp'])) {
    $output = pow($output, $input);    
} else if (isset($_REQUEST['equal'])) {
    $output = $input;  
} else {
    $input = 0.0;
}

?>
<form name="calculator" action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="last_activity" value="<?php echo $lastActivity?>" />
    <input class="res" type="text" readonly="readonly" size="23px" value="Result:" />
    <input class="res" type="text" readonly="readonly" size="20px" value="Input:" />
    <input class="res" type="text" readonly="readonly" size="10px" value="Operations:" /><br>
    <input name="output" type="text" readonly="readonly"  value="<?php echo $output?>"/>
    <input name="input" type="text" onfocus="this.value=''" value="<?php echo $input?>" />
    <input id="add" name="add" type="submit" value="+" />
    <input id="subtract" name="subtract" type="submit" value="-" />
    <input id="multiply" name="multiply" type="submit" value="*" />
    <input id="divide" name="divide" type="submit" value="/" />
    <input id="exp" name="exp" type="submit" value="^" />
    <input id="equal" name="equal" type="submit" value="=" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is alright to use javascript(JQuery) in your solution I would avoid using php to gather the user input.  It is more suitable for server side processing. Below is your code restructured to use javascript.

I removed the px from your input text elements size attribute(it is not necessary and will not validate properly).

I hope it helps.

-Larry

```
                  <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>PHP Calculator</title>
 <style type="text/css">
#add {
color:black;
background-color:#F55;
}
#subtract {
color:black;
background-color:#55f;
}
#multiply {
color:black;
background-color:#5f5;
}
#divide {
color:black;
background-color:#ff5;
}
#exp {
color:black;
background-color:#fa2;
}
#equal {
color: black;
background-color:#ccc;
}
.res {
color: black;
font-style: italic;
background-color:#eee;
border: none;
}
```

```
  <form id="calculator" name="calculator" action="index.php" method= "GET">
  <input class="res" type="text" readonly="readonly" size="23" value="Result:" />
  <input class="res" type="text" readonly="readonly" size="20" value="Input:" />
  <input class="res" type="text" readonly="readonly" size="10" value="Operations:" /><br/>
  <input id="output" name="output" type="text" readonly="readonly"  value=""/>
  <input id="input" name="input" type="text" value="" />
  <input id="add" name="add" type="button" value="+" />
  <input id="subtract" name="subtract" type="button" value="-" />
  <input id="multiply" name="multiply" type="button" value="*" />
  <input id="divide" name="divide" type="button" value="/" />
  <input id="exp" name="exp" type="button" value="^" />
  <input id="equal" name="equal" type="submit" value="=" />
  </form>

 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $("input").on("click",function(){//begin on click function

  //if the input elements value is not equal to "="
  if($(this).attr("value") !== "="){//begin if then

  //set the #input element to its current value plus the new value
  $("#input").val($("#input").val() + $(this).attr("value"));

  }//end if then

 });//end on click function

 $("#equal").on("click",function(e){//begin on click function

  //prevent form from submitting
  e.preventDefault();

  //evaluate the expression and store the result
  //todo:escape input if it could cause a security threat
  var expression = eval($("#input").val());

  //display the result in the #output input element
  $("#output").val(expression);

  });//end on click function

  </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: actually I really try to do it without javascript :-) but thanks